# why canvas is not behaving properly?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I want `CANVAS` (gray part) to always cover the screen.
But it covers too much.
 What to do?
(I don't want to use CSS)

```js
resize();

function resize() {
  document.getElementById("can").style.width = window.innerWidth + "px";
  document.getElementById("can").style.height = window.innerHeight + "px";
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#can {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<body onresize="resize();">
  <canvas id="can" />
</body>
```

Comment: Why don't you use the SO snippets instead of CodePen?

Comment: @Archit Gargi Here you can resize

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: A much simpler solution to what you are doing is that you set the width and height of the canvas to `100vw` and `100vh` respectively.

Comment: Better to observe the size of the convas container with ResizeObserver than onresize of the window. Also you might (will?) run into drawing issues if you don't set the `width` and `height` attrs instead of, or alongside (for retina downsampling), the style props

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `display: block;` css to your canvas.

```js
resize();

function resize() {
  document.getElementById("can").style.width = window.innerWidth + "px";
  document.getElementById("can").style.height = window.innerHeight + "px";
}

window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#can {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="can" />
```